How to add a float to an enumerate
So I decided to use LaTeX to do my homework, but I'm facing a little problem, the first image shows how I want it to be, the second image shows how I manage to get it, my temporal solution is to use a minipage to divide the page and a second minipage with a single column tblr, but as it doesn't align it properly, so I'd like to know how to properly add that kind of frame.
Minimal (I think) working code https://pastebin.com/38wNNtSZ of my example, but after adding the \noindent before the minipage it worked :D



Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you also post the code you used to make your attempt, along with the minimal necessary preamble?  That way, we can copy and paste to get what you get.

One problem I see is that the first minipage is indented by a \parindent.  To get rid of that, just precede it by \noindent.  Other differences can be diagnosed more easily when there is an example file to examine.

Welcome. // Usually the number of lines typeset will vary between the list and the frame. How do you want the result to look like in both cases (L>R, R>L)?

Please copy-paste the code into your question. Questions shouldn't rely on external links. But I guess this is next time as you seem to have solved the problem now. Is it OK to close this?

Yes, you can close it
